# Custom RoundedRectangle Shape

Tags: swiftui, shapes

I am working on a project with a custom roundedRectangle Shape that have a bump in one of its side, and from what i researched i have to draw a shape using  custom path...
however i wan't very successful in doing so, and i don't understand how to create it.

I would be grateful if someone help me create the shape in this attachment:
[image: Custom RoundedRectangle with a bump]

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is generally more receptive to questions like this if you show your previous attempts. Otherwise, it just seems like a request for someone to write code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw custom shapes with rounded corners, `.addArc` is your friend.

```
struct LabelShape: Shape {
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat
    let tabWidth: CGFloat
        
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: rect.height))
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: 0), radius: cornerRadius)
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: 0), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: cornerRadius)
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.width - tabWidth, y: 0), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: rect.width - tabWidth, y: rect.height), radius: cornerRadius)
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.width - tabWidth, y: cornerRadius * 2), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: 0, y: cornerRadius * 2), radius: cornerRadius)
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: 0, y: cornerRadius * 2), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height), radius: cornerRadius)
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height), radius: cornerRadius)
        return path
    }
}
```

which you can use like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
            LabelShape(cornerRadius: 10, tabWidth: 110)
                .stroke(.red)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
            HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline, spacing: 4) {
                Text("01:59:43")
                    .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold))
                Text("Hours")
                    .font(.system(size: 10, weight: .regular))
            }
            .padding(4)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

For a great explanation on how this version of `addArc` works, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71683201/123632

Comment: Thanks i have implemented this and it works, i had a hard time understanding how to move the arc and especially how to make that upper section dynamic, thanks again i really appreciate it.